# Problem with comparison within a trigger statement using a variable gotten from query

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I am trying to use an attribute from a 2nd table in the trigger of the 1st. To do this I am trying to load that value into a variable and then use it as a comparison.
However whenever I try and test the process the comparison answers false.

```
DELIMITER $$

create trigger evolve_persona before update on phantom_thieves

for each row begin 

set @t := (select tier from persona where pname = old.persona);

if((new.persona != old.persona) and (select cast(@t as unsigned) = '1')) then
set

new.st = old.st+10, new.ma = old.ma+10, new.en= old.en+10, new.ag= old.ag+10, 

new.lu= old.lu+20;

end if;

end$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Is `old.persona` null? The comparison will fail because null is not equal or unequal to anything, not even another null.

Comment: No it is instantiated

Answer (score 0):

I can see nothing wrong with your trigger but, this is somewhat more complicated as be written in a comment.

Make please following

```
SET @t = -1;

SELECT @t; -- returns -1

update phantom_thieves SET .....

SELECT @t; -should display at sometime 1
```

This seems to be the only problem that tier don't has the response 1 and with above, you can see what you get.